# Ajax send text over 1MB on fastcomet host

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am on Fastcomet host, it has been fine with passing data with ajax for over 1MB. But it suddenly not working.

To test,I made a text file just with letter "a".

- file 1 : 800,000 character count of letter "a" , file size:781.26KB
- file 2 : 1,200,000 character count of letter "a", file size: 1.14MB

Both files are able to read, file 1 is able to save back, but file 2 cannot. Both files are in the same folder, and save back also to the same folder.
No php error shows up, just file_put_contents is false, and file not saved.

Ajax code:

```
function AwaitSaveJsonZip ( filename , data   )
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'test_app_saveJson_1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {data:data , file:filename} ,
        dataType: "text",
    });
}
```

php save json (test_app_saveJson_1.php):

```
$data = $_POST['data']; 
$filename = $_POST['file']; 
if(!file_put_contents ($filename , $data , LOCK_EX )) {
    print ("fail-" . $filename) ;
}else
{
    print ( "success-" .  $filename  )   ; 
}
```

I tried to increase the limit in the php.ini, but nothing changed.
my php.ini :

```
php 5.6.40
max_execution_time  3600    
max_file_uploads    20  
max_input_nesting_level 10000
max_input_time  3600
max_input_vars  10000
memory_limit    1G
post_max_size   512M
upload_max_filesize 512M
```

Is there any php.ini settings I can change to solve? Or is there any POST limit with ajax for text over 1MB?Thanks for the help!

Comment: It may output a warning...have you checked to see if warnings are being logged in the PHP error log file?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the files, nothing shows up in the error log.